# Angular-Google -Maps - map renders incorrectly when resized for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I have implemented my map, however, when i view the map on a mobile or a resolution lower than 768px the map renders incorrectly.  It seems to be loading all of the map tiles in the top left hand corner and then again in full and correctly?

I have tried to set the resize event but this has no effect.

***Heres my code***

```
<ui-gmap-google-map zoom="10" center="map.center" events="map.events" class="col-md-12 map_canvas">
    <ui-gmap-marker ng-repeat="m in markers" coords="m.coords" idkey="m.id">
        <ui-gmap-window ng-if="m.response">
            <div class="google-window row-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                     <h1>Driver Detail</h1>

                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-4 row-title">Name:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">{{m.response.lastName}}, {{m.response.firstName.substring(0, 1)}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-4 row-title">VRM:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-8">{{m.response.vrm}}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">
                        <div class="col-md-4 row-title">Lat/Lng:</div>
                        <div class="col-md-8"><a href="{{m.gLink}}" target="_blank" class="google-link-marker">{{m.response.latitude + "/" + m.response.longitude}}&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ui-gmap-window>
    </ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And my JS

```
$scope.map = {
    zoom: 10,
    center: [{
        latitude: response[0].latitude,
        longitude: response[0].longitude
    }, {
        latitude: response[response.length - 1].latitude,
        longitude: response[response.length - 1].longitude
    }],
    options: {
        // draggable: false
    },
    events: {
        tilesloaded: function (map, eventName, args) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        }
    }
};
```

***Normal desktop resolution***

[image: before]

***After resize < 768px***

[image: after]

Comment: Could you put up a screenshot? Ive noticed that if the maps initialise before its containing elements have their height and width, it can cause issues. You could perhaps put an `ng-if` on the map to prevent it from loading until the other elements have

Comment: I see you don't have enough rep to post a screenshot -> I have bumped you.

Comment: @Chris I have added an ng-if which looks at $scope.showMap.  i have wired this to an interval for 3 seconds.  Still i get the same issue?

Comment: If you refresh the browser with the size already set, does it work? I.e. is it a resize issue or a startup issue.

Comment: @Chris no.  i can load it in mobile size and i still have the issue.  Also when i load it on my mobile phone.  I have also tried removing all non required css libs such as Bootstrap and Kendo-ui but still the issue persists

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to occur when the zoom level is less than 14.  very odd.  if i set the zoom level above this, the problem goes away.

This may well be a setting within the angular-google-maps lib that can be set.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map zoom="13" center="map.center" events="" class="col-md-12 google-map">
```